# How to disable button runtime in click event?

Tags: java, android, android-button

I searched on Google and StackOverflow but I did not find really what I need. I want to disable a button runtime in a click event but it does not work. I have 2 buttons whose names are ButtonA and ButtonB

My code:

```
 ButtonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {             
         ButtonA.setEnabled(false); 
         ButtonA.invalidate();
         ButtonB.setEnabled(true);
         ButtonB.invalidate();
     }
 });

 ButtonB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View arg0) {             
         ButtonB.setEnabled(false); 
         ButtonB.invalidate();
         ButtonA.setEnabled(true);
         ButtonA.invalidate();
     }
 });
```

I use onclick listener events in my list adapter class
If I refresh the screen it works but I want to do it runtime. When I click the button I want to see it will be disabled.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `it does not work` - what does it mean? Buttons are not being disabled? onClick() doesn't fire? The code doesn't compile? Also, are you setting up the buttons in onCreate()? Please post complete code where you are setting them up.

Comment: I mean , the button does not seen disabled

Comment: Please update your post with requested information.

Comment: I use onclick listener events in my list adapter class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clickable()` method for this.

```
ButtonA.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {              
         ButtonA.setClickable(false); 
         ButtonA.invalidate();
         ButtonB.setClickable(true);
         ButtonB.invalidate();
    }
});


ButtonB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {              
        ButtonB.setClickable(false); 
        ButtonB.invalidate();
        ButtonA.setClickable(true);
        ButtonA.invalidate();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this:

```
Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnB);
b.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: how can I put it to onclick event?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is :
 it should be defined by final,
like this;

```
final Button ButtonA,ButtonB;
```